# Can I echo my password to two commands?

Tags: bash, ssh, tee, sshfs

I'd like to login to a remote machine, and mount my home dir there with a single command. I tried to do it with:

```
echo myPassword | tee "sshfs boriskh@85.143.104.141:/share/home/boriskh /home/boris/Work/molDyn/boriskh@hpchead" | ssh -Y boriskh@85.143.104.141
```

but it doesn't work. `tee` says that it doesn't know the -Y option, and if quote both commands - it also works wrong.

**Edit**:

I found that these thiings put separately also don't work:

```
echo myPassword | ssh -Y boriskh@85.143.104.141
echo myPassword | sshfs boriskh@85.143.104.141:/share/home/boriskh /home/boris/Work/molDyn/boriskh@hpchead
```

**Edit2**:

To get the required functionality (mounting the remote home and also login there - in a single command with no password prompts) can be easily achieved with keys (with no passphrase - i.e. input `Enter` as a code):

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub boriskh@85.143.104.141
```

That's it. After that the desired functionality is achieved with:

```
sshfs boriskh@85.143.104.141:/share/home/boriskh /home/boris/Work/molDyn/boriskh@hpchead && ssh -Y boriskh@85.143.104.141
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for that task it should be more comfortable and secure use public keys. It's really easy and there [are lot of tutorials](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/530).

Remember not put anything in the passphrase, or it will be like have to type the password.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Francisco Puga. But sometimes you really have to do things like this (dirty) and the solution is [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)

Comment: Thanks - I'll try to learn implementation on python - `pexpect`.

Comment: In your case it's not recommended ! ;)